# Can I have a hit-point in VisualStudio that skips lines?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I often run into the situation where I want to disable some code while debugging without actually changing the code.

What I end up doing is having a break-point (usually conditional) and then when the break-point fires I perform a *Set Next Statement*. This can be very labor intensive when the code is reached many times so I created a macro:

```
Sub Skip3Lines()
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.LineDown(False, 3)
    DTE.Debugger.SetNextStatement()
End Sub
```

I then changed my break-point to be a hit-point (`right-click -> When Hit...`) and told it to execute this macro.

Visual studio was all too happy to spit out the following dialog box:

> `---------------------------`
>   `Error`
>   `---------------------------`
>   `A macro called a debugger action which is not allowed while responding to an event or  while being run because a breakpoint was hit.`
>   `---------------------------`
>   `OK`
>   `---------------------------`

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: You can also do this using a tracepoint: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14695736/301729

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DTE.ExecuteCommand("Debug.SetNextStatement")

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't get around the changing code bit, but how about a local boolean? Wrap the code you want to conditionally skip with an if statement. Default it to true and re-initialize it every time. Then, assuming you can write a macro that changes this value to false, you can enable/disable the hit-point on demand.

Never done this before, so you can tell me if macros don't work like this. I usually just use edit-and-continue, commenting out the code I want to skip. Of course it doesn't work if the code has a lambda or anonymous type/method in it though.

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to detect whether it's in debug mode, then use an if statement to have code not run, here's more information

http://weblogs.asp.net/jkey/archive/2003/11/23/39383.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Could you not use compiler condtitions in this instance?

```
#IF Config = "Debug" Then
    ' do my debug code here
#Else
   ' do my normal coding here
#End if
```