# Visual Studio 2008 Debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

I have an application that has two distinct parts, one operation that process data and adds it to a database and a second operation that retrieves the data and makes a report.  Is there a way to tell the debugger to start at the second operation of the application?  Previously I've commented out what I didn't want to run and worked around my issue in that way.  Is there a better way?  Thanks.

Comment: Unclear. Is that one process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have two methods in one piece of code, such as a Main method?

```
Main() 
{
   DoOperationOne();
   DoOperationTwo();
}
```

An easy way to skip over one is to read about [Set the Next Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09yze4a9.aspx).

Comment: this looks promising.  Thank you.

Comment: @Jim- you might want to make this process less painful by looking at this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455290/can-i-have-a-hit-point-in-visualstudio-that-skips-lines

Answer (score 2):

Breakpoints?  E.g. assuming the app structure is

```
DoTheFirstPart()
DoTheSecondPart()
```

put a breakpoint on the second part and run in the debugger, and then once you hit the breakpoint, do whatever other debugging you need (add more breakpoints, turn on catch-all-exceptions, etc.)  This will still run the first part - it's unclear to me if that's what you want or not.

(Question is a little vague, it's unclear what strategies you know/tried and what your goal is.)

Comment: for the confusion on the question, I really doubt that his application is that simple and structured :P

Answer (score 1):

If your language has an equivilent to #ifdef you could use that and a runtime parameter to avoid repeatedly commenting out code.

Edit: This assumes you don't want the first operation to run for whatever reason, question's a bit vague.

Comment: I _think_ the OP is ideally trying not to modify the original program (e.g. "is there a better way" == "I have this great tool called Visual Studio, but I am unsure what feature to use to do X").  But I am not 100% sure.  In any case, if you modify the original program, the question isn't too interesting.

Comment: I'm not sure why you got downvoted since the user did actually say he was currently commenting out the code. Rather than use comments, a much better way would be to use a #if _DEBUG as you suggested. Have one vote from me ;)

Comment: I would also concur for this being a correct answer. If you really want to use the debug features of Visual Studio and only want to focus on one area, this would certainly be a good way to skip a set of events your not interested or setup a set of test data automatically and jump to the section of code you are interested in. +1 from me too. Not sure why this got down voted ;-)

Comment: ahh...Conditional Methods...what i don't know could fill a book.  This is great. Thanks fellas