# Where to get a full list of debugger variables?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I'm trying to set a tracepoint to print hit count in VS but I cannet find any sort of $NAME to use in print message dialog. I tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/232dxah7(v=vs.100).aspx but I'm unable to find any link that describes every possible value I can output. Previously I used VB macro that I have written for this purpose, but unfortunately it runs too slow and can lead to very high delays that are unacceptable on my environment. Maybe somebody can point me to some article where I can pick enough of information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN states: You can include programmatic information in the message by using DebuggerDisplayAttribute syntax (see DebuggerDisplayAttribute). Here are a couple of examples

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx

Have a look at this Q&A:
[What expressions are allowed in tracepoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695724/what-expressions-are-allowed-in-tracepoints)

Comment: This is not helpful. DebuggerDisplayAttribute is only for .NET and allows the code to be customized to display diagnostic info in debugger window. My case need the code not to be modified, is written in C++(not managed) and I want the tracepoint to output breakpoint hits count. This article doesn't tell how to do this without using VBA macros.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want but you can achieve this by declaring a variable in the Immediate window with execution stopped ie:

```
int hitCount;
```

Then in Breakpoint -> When Hit -> Print a Message enter:

Hit Count : {hitCount}