# Return from a function using a breakpoint

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

Is it possible to automatically return from a function using a Breakpoint/Tracepoint?
I don't want to drag the execution point or set it with CTRL+SHIFT+F10 every time the breakpoint is hit.
I tried "printing" the following "messages" When Hit, but the executions continue without change.

```
{return;}
{return null;}
```

Note that I need to return from the function without actually changing code.

To clarify what a Tracepoint is: *"A tracepoint is a breakpoint with a custom action associated with it. When a tracepoint is hit, the debugger performs the specified tracepoint action instead of, or in addition to, breaking program execution."* From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktf38f66%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

If you don't know what I mean with "printing messages", you might want to read [this AltDevBlogADay post](http://altdevblogaday.com/2011/05/19/a-taste-of-live-code-editing-with-visual-studios-tracepoints/) about Tracepoints. It's good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, after a bit of digging around you *can* do this - but it's not going to work in all cases.

Beware, this uses macros and can't be guaranteed to work with inline delegates; or with methods that actually need to return something.  It automates the process described by @juergen d and @Erno when a breakpoint is hit; using very simple heuristics to find where the end of the current function is.

You first need to add this macro to your macros environment (open with ALT+F11 in VS).  This code is probably not as good as it could be as I've just rushed it out :)

```
Sub ExitStack()
    'get the last-hit breakpoint
    Dim breakPoint As EnvDTE.Breakpoint
    breakPoint = DTE.Debugger.BreakpointLastHit()
    'if the currently open file is the same as where the breakpoint is set
    '(could search and open it, but the debugger *should* already have done that)
    If (DTE.ActiveDocument.FullName = breakPoint.File) Then

        Dim selection As EnvDTE.TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
        Dim editPoint As EnvDTE.EditPoint
        'move the cursor to where the breakpoint is actually defined
        selection.MoveToLineAndOffset(breakPoint.FileLine, breakPoint.FileColumn)

        Dim codeElement As EnvDTE.CodeElement
        codeElement = DTE.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.FileCodeModel.CodeElementFromPoint(selection.ActivePoint, vsCMElement.vsCMElementFunction)
        'if a function is found, move the cursor to the last character of it
        If Not (codeElement Is Nothing) Then
            Dim lastLine As EnvDTE.TextPoint

            lastLine = codeElement.GetEndPoint()
            selection.MoveToPoint(lastLine)
            selection.StartOfLine(vsStartOfLineOptions.vsStartOfLineOptionsFirstText)
            'execute the SetNextStatement command.  
            'Has to be done via ExecuteCommand
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Debug.SetNextStatement")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

With that in place, now you can set your breakpoint - right click on it and hit the `When hit...` menu option (this only works in VS2010 I believe).  ScottGu describes this in [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/18/debugging-tips-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx) blog post.

From the dialog, find the `ExitStack` macro that you've just pasted in.

Run the code with the debugger attached and when the breakpoint is hit the rest of the function's code should be skipped.  This should obey other debugger tricks - like conditions etc.

Note - I used [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455290/can-i-have-a-hit-point-in-visualstudio-that-skips-lines) to solve a problem I was having; originally I was invoking the debugger's SetNextStatement method directly and it didn't work

I have no idea how methods that should return will behave - in theory they should return whatever the return value local is at the time, but in some cases the fact is this simply won't work!

Equally if the breakpoint is in a try/catch block then it won't work - because the try/catch has to be exited before you can set the next statement to somewhere outside of it.

Comment: Pretty cool. I'm still hoping someone has a non-macro, value-returning answer, but this is the best one so far.

Comment: @Protectorone there isn't one - unless you write your own debugger.  If a method returns a local variable you can use watch (or even use another macro) to set the local before using this one to return.

Answer (score 8):

In Visual Studio you could just drag the arrow, that indicates the current code line while debugging, to the end of the function.

Comment: +1, or right-click a return statement in the function, or the curly brace and select 'set next statement'.

Although it's worth pointing out that it only works when pointing code somewhere else in the current stack; and I think try/catch blocks can't be in effect.

Comment: I want it automatically. I don't want to drag the execution point every time the breakpoint hits.

Comment: Then consider the `goto` command like that: `if(your_breakpoint_condition) goto end_marker;`

Comment: But then I would need to put a label inside my code, right? Or do pseudo-labels exist that I can always `goto`? (Note that I can't change the code.)

Comment: If you can't change the code even a little bit then that is no option for you.

Comment: actually there is a way you can do this, in simple cases. @Protectorone - I'm putting an answer up that might help.

Answer (score 3):

Two options:

1. If you want the function to complete its execution and break after returning to the caller. Press "Step Out" (Shift-F11)
2. If you want to skip the execution of several lines, drag the yellow marker to the next line you want to execute. Remember, dragging the marker to a location might cause an order of execution that can never happen when running without interfering so the result might be completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this directly using a tracepoint.

1. Find the address of the return statement at the bottom of the function by breaking on it once, and then looking at the EIP register either in the Registers window or add a Watch for "@eip".
2. Add a tracepoint to the line you want to jump from. Remember that the jump will occur before anything on the line is executed. The content of the tracepoint should be `{@eip = address}` using the address from step 1.
3. Profit!

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/14695736/301729

Comment: Assuming the function _has_ a return statement…

Comment: @Protectorone Actually you don't even need a return statement. You should be able to break on the final closing curly brace and use that address.